# ¿Como enviar paramentros a un web worker?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backgroundworker

tengo un problema que me tiene loco hace horas.

Estoy intentando utilizar un *Web Worker* para traer notificaciones de manera tal que mientras el usuario se encuentra trabajando este se este ejecutando en segundo plano y le avise cuando tiene notificaciones nuevas.

El problema es cuando intento enviar información a este *Web Worker*. Muestro código

*Script A:*

```
function Work(){
var FID = $('.notificaciones input').val();
var work = new Worker(thisURL + "js/worker/worker.js");
work.postMessage({
    "thisURL": thisURL,
    "pdrr": cookie.get('pdrr'), 
    "FID":FID});
work.onmessage = function(e){
    var data = e.data
    Notificaciones(data);
}
}
Work();
```

*Script B:*

```
var data;
self.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    data = e.data;
})
function getNot(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         postMessage(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
}
xhr.open('POST', data.thisURL + "php/index.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("req=" + data.ppdr + "-get-notificacion&array[FID]=" + data.FID);
}
setInterval(getNot(), 1000);
```

No logro que los datos obtenidos en *self.onmessage* se guarden en la variable y trabajen en la función *getNot();*.

Según lo que parece se ejecuta primero la función y luego el *self.onmessage*,
¿Que debería hacer para que los paramentos se guarden en esa variable y se ejecute luego en la función?

Comment: son funciones asyncronas....[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) en fin puedes hacerlo con una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)  con [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) cambiar `new XMLHttpRequest()` por [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) con [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Comment: Con la promesa me funciono perfectamente. Gracias.